# How append filtered string to new list in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to append a string to new list that filtered from old list.

What I've tried so far:

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']

thai = []
japanese = []


def filter_str(lang):
    if 'tha' in lang:
        return True
    else:
        return False


filter_lang = filter(filter_str, languages)
thai = thai.append(filter_lang)

print(thai)
```

My expected output is:

```
['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']
thai = [x for x in languages if 'thai' in x]
print(thai)
```

Outputs:

```
['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
```

To help you understand the logic of this oneliner, see the following example based on your code:

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']

thai = []

def filter_str(lang):
    if 'tha' in lang:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for x in languages:
    if filter_str(x):
        thai.append(x)

print(thai)
# ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
```

The `for` loop that checks whether the string `'tha'` occurs (in this example with the help of your function), is the same logic as the list comprehension above (although with the first example you wouldn't even need the function). You could also use a list comprehension in combination with your function:

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']

def filter_str(lang):
    if 'tha' in lang:
        return True
    else:
        return False

thai = [x for x in languages if filter_str(x)]

print(thai)
# ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
```

Comment: Thank you, got more understanding about list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `filter` with lambda function

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']
thai = list(filter(filter_str,languages))  # or  thai = list(filter(lambda x:'thai' in x,languages))

print(thai)    #['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
```

or list comprehension

```
thai = [y for y in languages if 'tha' in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the next instead of using `thai.append`:

```py
thai.extend(filter(filter_str, languages))
```

Answer (score 0):

- [startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method returns True if a string starts with the specified prefix(string). If not, it returns False.

**Ex.**

```
languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']

thai = []
japanese = []

for x in languages:
    if x.startswith("tha"):
        thai.append(x)
    else:
        japanese.append(x)
print(thai)
print(japanese)
```

**O/P:**

```
['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03']
['jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a comprehension? e.g.

```
thai = [x for x in languages if filter_str(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer functional style, you can use [`operator.methodcaller()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
from operator import methodcaller

languages = ['thai01', 'thai02', 'thai03', 'jap01', 'jap02', 'jap03']
thai = list(filter(methodcaller('startswith', 'tha'), languages))
```